# How can I attach my JWT token to every axios call?

Tags: axios, next.js, next-auth

I'm working on my very first nextjs application. I'm using an axios instance to handle my calls to backend

```
export const httpClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${process.env.BASE_URL}`,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application/json',
  },
});
```

I'm also using next-auth to handle my authentication and authorization

```
const callbacks = {
  async jwt(token, user) {
    if (user) {
      token.accessToken = user.access_token;
    }
    return token;
  },

  async session(session, token) {
    session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
    return session;
  },
};
```

The call to the authentication endpoint is working correctly. If I `console.log()` the api response I can see the returned JWT token.

I'm now trying to attach that JWT token to every axios request but the call `await getSession()` is always `null`. I wrote following request interceptor

```
httpClient.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    const session = await getSession();
    if (session) { // this never evaluates to true. Session is always `null`
      console.log(session);
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${session?.accessToken}`;
    }

    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);
```

Following the docs, I wrapped my `_app.js` `<Component>` with

```
<Provider session={pageProps.session}>
   <Component {...pageProps} />
</Provider>
```

Any ideas what I could try next?

Edit:
I call `const [session, loading] = useSession();` on another part of the code (in the nextjs frontend) and there everything seems to be working

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with your getSession() function. Can you post it too?

Comment: the getSession() function is part of the next-auth library. Did not write it myself.

Comment: Where are the `axios` instance & interceptor being declared?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you're asking. What do you mean where?

Comment: I'm having the same issue where getSession() always returns null, were you able to solve this ?

Comment: I was able to solve it but it was something very specific to my project. If you can attach your code (maybe in another question) I can help you check it out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if the axios call is made on the server side, then the interceptor will also be executed on the server side.

If that is the case, when calling `getSession()` on the server side, you also have to pass it the request or the context (see the note at the bottom of the [manual entry for getSession](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#getsession))